# CMake create custom target with dependency on generated file

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command

In CMake, I want to create a custom target with a dependency on a generated file.

It would be along the lines of:

```
configure_file(conf.py.in conf.py)

add_custom_target(doc
  COMMAND ${SPHINX_EXECUTABLE} -b html ${SPHINX_SOURCE} ${SPHINX_BUILD}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
  COMMENT "Generating documentation with Sphinx"
  DEPENDS conf.py)
```

I.e. I would like to avoid *unconditionally* generating `conf.py`; I would rather have a custom target with a dependency on it and thereby limit when `conf.py` is generated.

How can I do this?

I don't quite understand how I can "integrate" `configure_file()` into the `add_custom_target()` (presumably the `COMMAND` or argument?), or make the latter "depend on" the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`configure_file` occurs during configuration.

`add_custom_target` occurs during the build step.

CMake is roughly broken up into 3 steps:

- Configure (`configure_file` will run during this step.)
- Generate
- Build (`add_custom_target` will run during this step.)

IE the file `configure_file` produces will be ready before `add_custom_target` by definition.

> I.e. I would like to avoid unconditionally generating conf.py; I would rather have a custom target with a dependency on it and thereby limit when conf.py is generated.

Then your work is already done. Configure file will only run when the input file changes.

From the CMake documentation: `If the input file is modified the build system will re-run CMake to re-configure the file and generate the build system again. The generated file is modified and its timestamp updated on subsequent cmake runs only if its content is changed.` - [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html)

As a result you don't need to `DEPEND` on this file. It's guaranteed to exist before the build starts.

```
# conf.py is now generated in the ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
# This is by default where configure_file places the output file
configure_file(conf.py.in conf.py)

# NOTE: By default commands are executed in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
# So you don't need to specify working directory.
add_custom_target(doc
  COMMAND ${SPHINX_EXECUTABLE} -b html ${SPHINX_SOURCE} ${SPHINX_BUILD}
  COMMENT "Generating documentation with Sphinx"
)
```